# Estimating the sample mean from countably infinite samples

Tags: distributions, mean, sample

Given a sample of $k$ numbers $x_1,...,x_k \in \mathbb{R}$, the sample mean is given by $$\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k x_i.$$

How do we compute the sample mean if we observe a sample of

$P1.$ $n$ intervals $[a_1,b_1],...,[a_n,b_n]$ where $a_i < b_i$ and $a_i,b_i \in \mathbb{R}$?

$P2.$ $n$ intervals (defined above) and a set of $k$ numbers?

If $n=1$, then intuition implies that the sample mean is $\frac{1}{2}\left (a_1+b_1 \right )$.

But how does one deal with the multiple intervals of different sizes and a mixture of points and intervals?

For $P1$, could the sample mean be

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{a_i}^{b_i} x\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{a_i}^{b_i}\mathrm{d}x}?$$

If that is correct, how would one deal with $P2$?

Comment: (1) Please explain how one "samples ... intervals."  What do those intervals *mean* and what model are you implicitly assuming about how "sampling" takes place?  (2) What does this question have with "countably infinite samples"?  All your examples have only a single sample and either $n$ or $n+k \lt \infty$ observations.

Comment: In the discrete case, one observes $k$ points. In the interval case, all the numbers between $a_i$ and $b_i$ are observed.

Comment: Please explain what it means to "observe" an interval.  There is more than one interpretation!

Comment: Perhaps, I have phrased it incorrectly. Each point in the interval is an observation, just like we had $k$ points in the discrete set. So, when there are $k$ points and one interval, the total number of observations is $k + S$ where $S$ is the the number of points in the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: That's untenable, because it's physically impossible to observe even countably infinitely many points.  (Intervals are *uncountable*, btw.)  The cardinality of an interval is just a distraction here: its consideration will not lead you anywhere useful.  It is crucial that you explain how such observations actually arise, as well as that you provide some indication of their meaning in that context.

Comment: The context is in image processing. Line segments and points are observed in an image and the mean value of all points which are observed (i.e. have a non-zero value in the image). In the image case, computing the mean is easy, since everything is discretized. My question is: if we represent the line segments with their endpoints (such that all points between them need to be included in the computation), can we still compute a mean?

Comment: Okay, that's a surprising interpretation--but an interesting one.  Could you explain how you intend to interpret this mean value?  That would give an important clue concerning how it should be computed.

Comment: In the discrete case, a normal distribution is fitted to all the observed points. I was hoping to do that but with observed line segments as well.

Comment: That suggests you might be attempting to form some kind of density estimate.  The solution still depends on what it means to "observe" a point or a line segment.  Exactly how do these arise in an image?  What do they represent?  What would that density estimate purport to reveal?

Comment: In the real world, the non-zero elements correspond to thresholded elements from an image of a coin. Some of the coins contain line segments in them, and this led to the current problem. The density estimate is used to figure out where in the image the coin may lie.

Comment: That's quite a bit different from estimating a mean!  Are you attempting to estimate the location of the coin's center from the thresholded elements that appear in an image?  If so, I can't help thinking that a good solution would have to incorporate some model of the thresholding process as well as a model of the coin itself.

Comment: OK, that's probably true. But is it possible to estimate a distribution from the non-zero elements of the image (in the way I described earlier)?

Comment: In a 2D image domain, "mathematical" point or line objects would both have 0 area. Discrete pixel-set point or line objects would both have area proportional to # pixels. (Or fractional weight/pixel could be allowed in the case of a grayscale.) Depending on your problem, really something like a [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) may be more suitable, a common method for object detection/pose estimation. (This would be a "model of the coin".)

Comment: The challenge concerns how one should weight line segments relative to points.  This is an example of a "change of support" problem.  In many applications, an entire segment's worth of data should *not* get the same weight as a corresponding number of points (or pixels).  How exactly to incorporate such disparate data really can't be adequately answered without a detailed consideration of their physical meaning and their statistical properties.

Comment: @GeoMatt There are [plenty of examples of the Hough transform](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Hough+transform) right here on CV.